# Why sysout allways prints 1?

Tags: java

In below code, why sysout allways prints 1?

```
public class A implements ActionListener{       
    public static int X = 0;
    private Timer timer;        
    public A(){
        timer = new Timer(16 ,this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(16);
        timer.start();      
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(X);
    }           
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new A();
        new B().start();
    }
}    
class B extends Thread{

    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        A.X++;      
    }
}
```

I expect something like this output:

```
1
2
3
...
```

Note that I dont want to use another approach.

Comment: what is the logic that you expect your program to have? Not just the output, but *why* is this the output that you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the run method of threads is called only once. If you want to see your expected result try this:

```
class B extends Thread{

public void run(){
      try {
           while(true){ //add here some condition when you want to stop the loop
               A.X++; 
               Thread.sleep(200);
           }
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I forget while statement